# How to solve a first order partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maple

I have a first order pde ($P_{14}$ is the unknown function in $a, b, a_1, b_1$):
\begin{align}
& -\frac{a}{a_1} \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial a} - \frac{a b}{a_1 b_1} \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial b} +  \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial a_1} + \frac{a}{a_1} \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial b_1}  = \frac{-P_{14}}{a_1} + \frac{a^2}{a_1}.
\end{align}
How to solve this equation? My work: multiply both sides of the equation by $a_1 b_1$, we obtain:
\begin{align}
& - ab_1 \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial a} - ab \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial b} + a_1 b_1 \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial a_1} + ab_1 \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial b_1}  = -b_1 P_{14} + a^2 b_1. (1)
\end{align}

I think that we need to solve the corresponding homogeneous equation 
\begin{align}
& - ab_1 \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial a} - ab \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial b} + a_1 b_1 \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial a_1} + ab_1 \frac{\partial P_{14}}{\partial b_1}  = 0
\end{align}
first.

Then we need to solve the equations
\begin{align}
\frac{da}{-ab_1} = \frac{db}{-ab} = \frac{da_1}{a_1b_1} = \frac{db_1}{ab_1}.
\end{align}

Can Maple solve equation (1) directly? What are the solutions of equation (1) (I don't have Maple on my computer)? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the equation is 
\begin{align}
P_{14} = -a^2+a F(a_1 a, b_1+a, b b_1),
\end{align}
where $F(x,y,z)$ is any function in $x,y,z$.